# Web Workers in Salesforce

Tags: webservices, javascript-remoting

I have a details button that when clicked sends the record (opportunity) for an Apex controller that sends this record to a web service (SOAP). The problem is that my browser comes to halt in sending the record. 
Does anyone know how I can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the problem when using a detail button on the record itself, the record is locked while waiting for transaction to complete.  Are you in any way updating the record with info received from the external SOAP service?  If so, you could delegate that to another @future method that handles the updating.

Otherwise you could have this functionality in a visualforce page that operates either inside a popup window or inline on the record.  That way you could update that page when the transaction completes to give the user some indication that the operation was successful or not.

Comment: Thank you. I will use the option of visual force page in a pop-up.